# Can iOS Game Center pass strings/objects between players in the game?

Tags: ios, object, game-center

Never used Game Center before in my apps. So be nice if the question is naive. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask either. :)

I'm currently thinking to make my app support Game Center, primarily for the purpose of promoting my app. My app actually is a puzzle like game, think of Crossword puzzles, so it's not a very much multi-player game. However, I think I can make it competitive: one makes puzzle and the other solves it; the second round, the players switch roles. Now, my question is if Game Center supports such format. For example, does Game Center allows user pass a string or other kind of objects to other player? If it does, then I can implement the puzzle (provided by one player) into a string and decode it at other players end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like exactly what the turn based game APIs introduced in iOS 5 are for. Check the GsmeKit docs.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're pointing me to the right direction. I give you an up now, and will wait a bit to accept it if no better answer appears. On 2nd thought, app Draw Something should be using this kit, right?